# How to create footer column dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**HTML**

```
<tfoot>
    <tr ng-repeat="prop in test" class="success">
        <th class="text-right">@{{prop}}</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

**Angularjs**

```
$scope.test = [
    $scope.transSummary.total.toFixed(2),
    $scope.transSummary.due.toFixed(2)
];
```

The above generates two of table footer instead of two columns. I did try `ng-repeat` in the tag `th` for generating two `tg` as columns but it does not work.

Comment: Can you make a working fiddle? So that we can understand the problem better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

https://jsfiddle.net/tufdjk2s/

```
<tr>
    <th ng-repeat="prop in test">{{prop}}</th>
</tr>
```